# How to sync two textareas?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I am trying to show whatever is typed/pasted/cut/deleted in one textarea in another textarea. But I'm having problem when backspace and delete is pressed. I'll probably have problem with deleting selections, cuting, pasting, undo, redo etc aswell. How can I best solve this problem? Code:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Live Text Sync</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <textarea id="a"></textarea>
  <textarea id="b"></textarea>
  <script>
   var a = document.getElementById("a");
   var b = document.getElementById("b");
   a.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if(!e.ctrlKey) {
     if (e.which >= 65) {//A
      var letter = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
      if (!e.shiftKey) letter = letter.toLowerCase();
      b.value = b.value.substring(0, a.selectionStart) + letter + b.value.substring(a.selectionEnd);
     } else if (e.which === 8) {//backspace
       var text = b.value;
       var till = a.selectionStart === 0 ? 0 : a.selectionStart - 1;
       b.value = text.substring(0, till) + text.substring(a.selectionEnd);
     } else if (e.which === 46) {//delete
      var text = b.value;
      var van = text.length < a.selectionEnd ? a.selectionEnd : a.selectionEnd + 1;
      b.value = text.substring(0, a.selectionStart) + text.substring(van);
     }
    }
    
   }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any reason not to use `.value` to sync 2 `textarea`s?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Live Text Sync</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="a"></textarea>
  <textarea id="b"></textarea>
  <script>
    var a = document.getElementById("a");
    var b = document.getElementById("b");
    a.oninput = function(e) {
      b.value = a.value;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```